# How to select a Post Type (Wordpress) to pass a filter in head?

Tags: php, wordpress, seo, canonical-link

I have a WordPress site which uses Yoast SEO to manage **canonical links** and **noindex meta robots**, among other things, with a very peculiar configuration.

By default, Yoast's plugin adds a `<link rel="canonical" href="...">` in every page. I'm not interested in show a canonical link in every single static page (whatever its type is) but in some type of posts: **Pages** and **Posts** (not Attatchment, Category, Archive, etc.)

I know the way to prevent Yoast from adding a canonical link by default, just adding the following code in functions.php: `add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', '__return_false' );`. But what if I just want to pass that filter in some post types? Or passing it in every page except some types of posts (both approaches are useful to me). Help would be much appretiated. Any?

UPDATE: Valid answer with some minor fixes

```
function remove_canonical_from_post_types($url) {
    $post_type = get_post_type();
    if ($post_type !== 'post' && $post_type !== 'page') { // If post type is not Post nor Page, doesn't add a canonical link in any case
        return false;
    }
    else { // It is Post or Page
        if (is_category() || is_author() || is_tag() || is_archive()) { // If page is post type 'Post' we don't want to add canonical in some sub-types: Category, Author, Tag, Archive
            return false;
        }
        return $url; // In any other case (Posts and Pages) adds a canonical link
    }
}
add_filter('wpseo_canonical', 'remove_canonical_from_post_types');
```

Comment: check with the `get_post_type()` function?

Comment: I've tryed:
`$post_type = get_post_type ( $post );

if ($post_type != 'page' || $post_type != 'post') {

add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', '__return_false' );

};`
And none, filter is still affecting to every static page (not adding a canonical-link in pages and posts)

Comment: I want the filter to be passed when the type is not `!=` 'page' nor `||` 'page'...

Comment: And doesn't work as expected anyway, both ways (`||` and `&&`) passes the filter to every page type, like the condition wouldn't be considered.

Comment: I was merely pointing out your logic was wrong in the if statement. You were saying "if it is not page or if it is not post" then do something. What you wanted to say was "if it is not page and it is not post either" then do something. Glad someone created a complete solution for you.

Comment: Yes @RST, you were right trying to get me in the right direction. Trank you for your advises too. Fortunately I have been able to get the code I was looking for, adding some changes to the code proposed by Luka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the provided "wpseo_canonical" filter and check there for the correct post type (and return false there).

Something like this:

```
function remove_canonical_from_post_types($url)
{
    $post_type = get_post_type();

    if ($post_type !== 'post' && $post_type !== 'page') {
        return false;
    }

    return $url;
}
add_filter('wpseo_canonical', 'remove_canonical_from_post_types');
```

Comment: Indeed, that's exactly what I needed! Thanks!